# ¿Como abrir un documento en otro IFRAME?

Tags: html

vengo con esta duda sobre Iframe la cosa es que quiero abrir un archivo pdf ubicado en un frame y que se visualice el otro hasta el momento he usado base target _parent pero no me ha funcionado

```
<frameset  rows="18%,*" cols="*">
<frame name="der1" src="Encabezado.html" noresize="no" scrolling="no">
```

Este es el menu

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li class="menu__item"> <a href="#" class="menu__link">Direccionamiento</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="menu__item" > <a href="Generalidades.html" class="menu__link">generalidades</a></li>
                
            </ul>
```

y quiero que aparezca en el cuerpo.html

este es el código resumido.

muchas gracias de ante mano